# How can I tell Cargo to rebuild when a file included with the include_bytes macro is changed?

Tags: rust, embedded-resource, rust-cargo

I am using the `include_bytes!` macro to compile a GLSL shader into a rust program. It seems that Cargo is unaware of this however: when I modify just the shader file and test it with `cargo run` the updated file is not compiled in. Manually touching the `.rs` file that includes the shader does work.

Do I need to add something to my `Cargo.toml` to explictly state this dependency?

Version info:

```
$ rustc --version && cargo --version
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (ecf8c64e1 2015-03-21) (built 2015-03-22)
cargo 0.0.1-pre-nightly (e689383 2015-03-16) (built 2015-03-16)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed in rustc: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24423

Answer (score 1):

Cargo has no way currently to add a file to the list of 'watched' files for changes. It won't know about files included with `include_bytes!` because that would involve special-casing that macro specifically.

Comment: Thanks. Is this something worth reporting as an issue somewhere?

Comment: @NicholasBishop, of course, you can suggest anything reasonable like this on the [Cargo issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues).

Comment: Hmm, the plot thickens a bit. I was putting together a minimal test to file the issue, and noticed that the include_str macro does seem to do the right thing, while include_bytes does not. I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'll dig a little further and see if I can spot the difference.

Comment: @NicholasBishop, Did you ever file that bug report you were about to? Did you find out why modifying a file included by `include_str!` causes a recompilation?

Comment: I had not filed the bug, thank you for reminding me. It's up now: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1510